# cocos2D game freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, freeze

I have a model object that stores an array of X,Y positions. The positions are arranged in a grid fashion. The model also has a givePositionForBlock method, which I use to set the position of tiles that spawn on the screen.

it randomly takes a position out of the array and checks if the distance if far enough away from a certain other tile controlled by the user. if it's not far enough away, it places the position back in the array and tries another one. It's this method that causes the freeze. there are no error logs or anything. it happens always at the same time when the emptyBlocks array is nearly empty (happens about 1 out of 3 times).

I realize this is because as the grid gets filled it becomes more more difficult to find a tile that is far enough away from the user controlled tile.

I tried to solve this by reducing the spawnOffset as the grid gets filled and at a certain point to simply ignore the spawnOffset rule. But it doesn't always seem to work. If I remove the while loop it works fine. But I need to have the check otherwise an object can spawn right in front of the user while playing.

```
- (CGPoint) givePositionForBlock {

    CGPoint position = [[self givePosition] CGPointValue];
    BOOL generatedPositionOk = NO;
    float spawnOffset = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 256: 128;

    GameScene *scene = [GameScene sharedGameScene];
    SnakePiece *snakeHead = [scene.tileArray objectAtIndex:0];

    int tries = 0;
    int maxtries = 50;

    // decrease the minimum required distance as the grid gets filled
    if ([emptyBlocks count] < 70 && [emptyBlocks count] > 35 ) {
        spawnOffset = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 128: 64;
    } else if ([emptyBlocks count] < 35 && [emptyBlocks count] > 20){
        spawnOffset = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 64: 32;
    } else if ([emptyBlocks count] < 20){ 
        generatedPositionOk = YES;
    }   

    // check if the position is far enough away. 
    while (generatedPositionOk == NO) {
        if ((position.x > snakeHead.position.x+spawnOffset || position.x < snakeHead.position.x-spawnOffset) ||
            (position.y > snakeHead.position.y+spawnOffset || position.y < snakeHead.position.y-spawnOffset )) {

            generatedPositionOk = YES;
            break;

        } else {
            //if not then put the position back in the array and take a new one. 
            //repeat until suitable position is found.
            [self insertPositionInEmptyBlocksArray:position];
            position = [[self givePosition] CGPointValue];
            generatedPositionOk = NO;
            tries++;

            //maximum amount of times it can try to find a suitable position. 
            //if the max is exceeded use the position anyway

            if (tries > maxtries) {
                generatedPositionOk = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    return position;
}
```

and here's the givePosition method used above.

```
- (NSValue *) givePosition {

    int x;
    CGPoint randomPointGl;

    if ([emptyBlocks count] > 0) {
        x = arc4random() % [emptyBlocks count];
        randomPointGl = [[emptyBlocks objectAtIndex:x]CGPointValue];
        [filledBlocks addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:randomPointGl]];
        [emptyBlocks removeObjectAtIndex:x];
    }
    return [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:randomPointGl];
}
```

Comment: when it freezes, set a breakpoint and check why your while loops runs infinitely

Comment: oh nice tip! I didn't know you could do that even when the game freezes. I think I've found the issue. Gonna do some more testing to be sure.

Comment: I don't think the game is freezing. As @LearnCocos2D mentioned, you're just being stuck in an infinite loop. Set breakpoints or writeout to console using `NSLog`

Comment: Nah, I think the code was just trying to go home. Apple, Cupertino, 1 Infinite Loop. :)